# Escaping MySQL characters in .NET

Tags: .net, mysql

Does anybody have any good .NET functions they can share to escape necessary MySQL query characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using the [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html)?  If you need to do something like parameterized queries, then it should provide "safe" and correct ways to do it, e.g. in [this example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could you give an example of the necessary characters? 
Without a context...you could try using "@" to give a literal string.

```
string query= @"select * from table"
```

Otherwise there is `String.Replace()`.

Comment: A C# literal string won't escape any MySQL-specific characters. It's a compile-time thing for C# with no effect whatsoever on any runtime parts.